# Forbidden: You are not authorized to perform the requested action

Tags: openstack-keystone

I am installing openstack devstack deploying identity ldap
I followed these steps:
i followed the step of the quick start installation of devstack too i created a local.conf file with the following contents:

```
 [[Local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=sesame
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
ENABLED_SERVICES=key,n-api,n-crt,n-obj,n-cpu,n-net,n-cond,cinder,c-sch,c-api,c-vol,n-sch,n-novnc,n-xvnc,n-cauth,horizon,mysql,rabbit,ldap
KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND=ldap 
KEYSTONE_CLEAR_LDAP=yes
LDAP_PASSWORD=sesame
```

then I started the installation ./stack.sh
I had the same problem after every installation attempt. please help me.

```
 CRITICAL keystone [None req-eac86609-c531-420b-8f0c-c05dbb1ea404 None None] Unhandled error: Forbidden: You are not authorized to perform the requested action.
ERROR keystone Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR keystone   File "/usr/bin/keystone-manage", line 10, in <module>
ERROR keystone     sys.exit(main())
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/manage.py", line 45, in main
ERROR keystone     cli.main(argv=sys.argv, config_files=config_files)
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/cli.py", line 1191, in main
ERROR keystone     CONF.command.cmd_class.main()
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/cli.py", line 178, in main
ERROR keystone     klass.do_bootstrap()
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/cli.py", line 169, in do_bootstrap
ERROR keystone     self.bootstrapper.bootstrap()
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/bootstrap.py", line 63, in bootstrap
ERROR keystone     self._bootstrap_admin_user()
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/bootstrap.py", line 207, in _bootstrap_admin_user
ERROR keystone     'password': self.admin_password
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/common/manager.py", line 116, in wrapped
ERROR keystone     __ret_val = __f(*args, **kwargs)
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/identity/core.py", line 416, in wrapper
ERROR keystone     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/identity/core.py", line 426, in wrapper
ERROR keystone     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/identity/core.py", line 967, in create_user
ERROR keystone     ref = driver.create_user(user['id'], user)
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/identity/backends/ldap/core.py", line 160, in create_user
ERROR keystone     self._disallow_write()
ERROR keystone   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/identity/backends/ldap/core.py", line 157, in _disallow_write
ERROR keystone     raise exception.Forbidden(READ_ONLY_LDAP_ERROR_MESSAGE)
ERROR keystone Forbidden: You are not authorized to perform the requested action.
ERROR keystone
+lib/keystone:bootstrap_keystone:1         exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:515                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:516                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:516                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:519                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.sbrPqeUJur ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:526                  rm /tmp/tmp.sbrPqeUJur
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:530                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:425               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:532                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:535                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  generate-subunit 1530240644 2563 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:538                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:541                  /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2018-06-29-033327.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:550                  exit 1
```

Comment: Do the user from which you are running the `./stack.sh` has `sudo` privileges ?